# Binding to not existing interface

Tags: networking, kernel, linux-kernel, interface, network-interface

I've just noticed the very weird situation I don't have a good explanation for.

The machine (debian) has one interface with one IP address assigned:

```
# ifconfig vmbr0 |grep inet
inet addr:192.168.1.26  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

In the some software settings (powerdns recursor if it's necessary) it is specified that its daemon binds to the following interfaces:

```
local-address=127.0.0.1 192.168.1.24
```

As you may have noticed, it was a mistake made in the IP address value, but the thing is - daemon successfully bound to it:

```
# netstat -nlp | grep 1.24 | grep 53
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.24:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      328862/pdns_recurso
udp        0      0 192.168.1.24:53         0.0.0.0:*                           328862/pdns_recurso
```

And what is more surprising - the switch successfully route traffic to this machine (there is no other `192.168.1.24` in the LAN, so no IP address conflicts).

So could anyone explain why it is possible and works?

I thought that kernel will only accept IP packets that have the correct destination and discard all others.

Comment: Use `ip addr`, not `ifconfig`. `ifconfig` is deprecated and missing a lot of stuff.

Comment: @Patrick I see now, it is there (I mean, it is assigned to the network interface) :-S May suit as an answer actually :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the address (192.168.1.24) is actually present on the host, but due to limitations in the `ifconfig` utility, it is not shown. Instead you should be using the [Iproute2](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2) utility `ip`, and not `ifconfig`. `ifconfig` has been deprecated in Linux for several years now, and is missing a lot of functionality. The specific bit of functionality affecting your case is the ability to add/show multiple IP addresses on a single interface (without creating interface aliases).

The method of adding multiple IP addresses to an interface with `ifconfig` is to create interface aliases (`eth0` -> `eth0:0` `eth0:1` etc). However you can only have 255 aliases on a single interface, so for some enterprise setups, this is a significant limitation.
With the Iproute2 `ip` utility, you can add an unlimited number of addresses to a single interface.

For example:

```
$ ip addr add 169.254.0.1 dev eth0
$ ip addr add 169.254.0.2 dev eth0

$ ifconfig eth0 | grep '\<inet\>'
        inet 192.168.0.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255

$ ip addr show dev eth0 | grep '\<inet\>'
    inet 192.168.0.20/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet 169.254.0.1/32 scope global eth0
    inet 169.254.0.2/32 scope global eth0
```

So notice how `ifconfig` is only showing one address, while `ip addr` is showing all of them.

Comment: I was looking for the answer to OP's question "*So could anyone explain why it is possible and works?*", but I didn't find it. Your response explains why to use iproute2 rather than ifconfig, but it fails to properly address OP's question.

Comment: @FabioA. The answer to that is subtly indicated in the comments on the question: "it is there (I mean, it is assigned to the network interface)". I've updated the answer to make this point more clear. Thanks for the feedback.